# Python convert string holding nested json to dict

Tags: python

I have the following list (notice "keyE" has a dictionary as a string):

```json
[
  {
    "keyA": "Example",
    "keyB": "{\"keyC\":2,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\"name\":\"foo\"}\"},\"keyF\":0}"
  },
  {
    "keyA": "Example2",
    "keyB": "{\"keyC\":6,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\"name\":\"bar\"}\"},\"keyF\":5}"
  }
]
```

And I want to convert it to this (it can have any number of nested dictionaries and lists):

```json
[
  {
    "keyA": "Example",
    "keyB": {
      "keyC": 2,
      "keyD": {
        "keyE": {
          "name": "foo"
        }
      },
      "keyF": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "keyA": "Example2",
    "keyB": {
      "keyC": 6,
      "keyD": {
        "keyE": {
          "name": "bar"
        }
      },
      "keyF": 5
    }
  }
]
```

So far, I have the following but I don't know what to do after the `json.loads`. I know I have to recursively call the function but not sure how.

```py
import json

def convert(data_list: list) -> list:
  for i in range(len(data_list)):
    obj = data_list[i]

    for key, value in obj.items():
      if isinstance(value, str) and any(char in "{[]}" for char in value):
        try:
          data = json.loads(value)
          # What do I do here?
        except:
          continue
```

Comment: How'd you get the data in the first place?

Comment: It's how some data is saved at work. I can't modify how it's saved so I need to parse it.

Comment: `try: obj[key] = json.loads(value)`, perhaps? But don't have a naked `except` - run it without the `try`, identify what exception `json.loads` gives when you feed it some non-JSON, then catch that specific exception.

Comment: `for i in range(len(thing)): item = thing[i]` is also ungood - you don't use `i` for anything else so might as well `for item in thing:` instead

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: You should tell whoever at work needs to hear it, this is a really shitty way to save data...

Comment: Hahaha, I know. I brought it up but since I just joined the team and they have thousands of records saved like this, they don't seem keen on changing it.

Comment: The problem here is that you're not going to be able to rely on `json.loads()` for JSON embedded inside JSON because `json.loads()` isn't going to be able to distinguish them: `json.loads()` isn't going to see `JS{JSON}ON` and know that the `{JSON}` needs to be processed first, before the `JS--ON`. You're literally going to need to write your own parser for this. To reiterate: `json.loads()` expects a valid JSON object. What you're passing it is a "valid" JSON object, where the embedded JSON objects just looks like strings.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I expected `json.loads` not to parse everything inside and that I would have to make a recursive function and do `json.loads` multiple times. Are you saying, that won't be possible?

Comment: It's not that easy because, well, what exactly do you pass to the recursive call? You have to determine the "scope" of each nested JSON object from both the "left" and the "right" side. A recursive solution would only work on a *nested structure*, but to Python, your data just looks like a flat string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested key seems like a JSON string that can be loaded into a dictionary using [**`json.loads`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) method.
Though the nested JSON won't get converted to the dictionary that's why I've added the recursive function to address the nested dictionary present in the JSON.

```
import json
from json import JSONDecodeError


def recurse(d):
    try:
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            loaded_d = d
        else:
            loaded_d = json.loads(d)
        for k, v in loaded_d.items():
            loaded_d[k] = recurse(v)
    except (JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
        return d
    return loaded_d


for d in data_list:
    for key, val in d.items():
        d[key] = recurse(val)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "keyA": "Example",
        "keyB": {"keyC": 2, "keyD": {"keyE": {"name": "foo"}}, "keyF": 0},
    },
    {
        "keyA": "Example2",
        "keyB": {"keyC": 6, "keyD": {"keyE": {"name": "bar"}}, "keyF": 5},
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; however, this won't go inside "keyE" and turn that JSON string into a dict. This will only do the outer cases. It can be any level deep.

Comment: @VishalSingh `keyB` is a string but not dict: `'keyB': '{"keyC":2,"keyD":{"keyE":"{"name":"foo"}"},"keyF":0}'` One more try?

Comment: Thank you. Did you use the same input as in the OP? I keep getting the following error when I try this code: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 29 (char 28)

Comment: @o.o yes I've used the same input. see here https://ideone.com/6xJDA9

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes. But `KeyB` is a string for your code (I mean result data)

Comment: @rzlvmp If you're talking about the Output, "keyB" is a dict. There are no quotes around the curly braces. It looks like it works for me too. Thank you Vishal!

Comment: @o.o no worries. happy to help. don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @a.a Really? looks like my python is acting different than yours. I copied this code as is and `print(data_list)` shows me: `[{'keyA': 'Example', 'keyB': '{"keyC":2,"keyD":{"keyE":"{"name":"foo"}"},"keyF":0}'}, {'keyA': 'Example2', 'keyB': '{"keyC":6,"keyD":{"keyE":"{"name":"bar"}"},"keyF":5}'}]`

Comment: @rzlvmp try here https://ideone.com/6xJDA9

Comment: @VishalSingh okay, and what you see in your own link (`stdout`)?

Comment: @rzlvmp you're right i see the wrong output.

Comment: Interesting, I see the correct output when running locally.

Comment: @rzlvmp it has something to do with escaping string. earlier i was seeing the correct output on my local ide.

Answer (score 2):

No idea if this'll work for your more complicated cases, but I was able to use `ast.literal_eval()` and some really janky chained `str.replace` calls:

```py
import ast


def replace(s):
    return ast.literal_eval(s.replace(r'"{', "{").replace(r'}"', "}"))


x = [{"keyA": "Example",
      "keyB": "{\"keyC\":2,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\"name\":\"foo\"}\"},\"keyF\":0}"},
     {"keyA": "Example2",
      "keyB": "{\"keyC\":6,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\"name\":\"bar\"}\"},\"keyF\":5}"}]


for d in x:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if "{" in value:
            d[key] = replace(value)
```

Output:

```py
In [4]: x
Out[4]:
[{'keyA': 'Example',
  'keyB': {'keyC': 2, 'keyD': {'keyE': {'name': 'foo'}}, 'keyF': 0}},
 {'keyA': 'Example2',
  'keyB': {'keyC': 6, 'keyD': {'keyE': {'name': 'bar'}}, 'keyF': 5}}]

In [5]: x[0]["keyB"]["keyD"]["keyE"]["name"]
Out[5]: 'foo'
```

Comment: hacky solution without recurse :) I like it

Comment: Extremely hacky. Likely to fail. I hate it :D

Comment: `r'"[ ]*{'` and `r'}[ ]*"'` will cover empty space cases

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is recursive solution:

```
import json
from json import JSONDecodeError

data = [
  {
    "keyA": "Example",
    "keyB": "{\"keyC\":2,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"foo\\\"}\"},\"keyF\":0}"
  },
  {
    "keyA": "Example2",
    "keyB": "{\"keyC\":6,\"keyD\":{\"keyE\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"bar\\\"}\"},\"keyF\":5}"
  }
]

def rec_convert(data):

  for k, v in data.items():
    try:
      if type(v) == dict:
        rec_convert(v)
        continue
      data[k] = json.loads(v)
      rec_convert(data[k])
    except (JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
      continue

for el in data:
  rec_convert(el)

print("raw print:")

print(data)

print("pretty print")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

and output:

```
raw print:
[{'keyA': 'Example', 'keyB': {'keyC': 2, 'keyD': {'keyE': {'name': 'foo'}}, 'keyF': 0}}, {'keyA': 'Example2', 'keyB': {'keyC': 6, 'keyD': {'keyE': {'name': 'bar'}}, 'keyF': 5}}]
pretty print
[
  {
    "keyA": "Example",
    "keyB": {
      "keyC": 2,
      "keyD": {
        "keyE": {
          "name": "foo"
        }
      },
      "keyF": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "keyA": "Example2",
    "keyB": {
      "keyC": 6,
      "keyD": {
        "keyE": {
          "name": "bar"
        }
      },
      "keyF": 5
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated Vishal Singh's answer to accommodate for lists inside a dictionary.

```
def decode_json_recursively(obj):
    try:
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            data = [decode_json_recursively(el) for el in obj]
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            data = obj
        else:
            data = json.loads(obj)

        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for k, v in data.items():
                data[k] = decode_json_recursively(v)
    except (JSONDecodeError, TypeError, AttributeError):
        return obj
    return data
```